# How to create/set up folder structure in website URL

Tags: html, url

can someone help on how to create/set up folder structure in website URL.

URL needs to be in the below format.

http://www.example.com/snippets/html

if you can post any tutorial links that would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please check the link [Want-To-Set-Up-Your-First-Site](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/reference/article.php/3472931/So-You-Want-To-Set-Up-Your-First-Site-Huh.htm)

[first-website-part1](https://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/how-to/first-website-part1.html)

[creating-files-folder-structure-web-pages](http://www.thehelloworldprogram.com/web-development/creating-files-folder-structure-web-pages/)

Comment: Thanks Rishal dev singh